# SearchView not working in Android . Why So?

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, adapter, searchview

I am using Recycleview with headers in my app and i am trying to implement searchview in my app but it is not Working. When i click on search view and type something the results are not filtered and i get this in my log cat.

```
2019-06-23 14:00:48.471 27193-27508/com.example.testapp W/Filter: An exception occured during performFiltering()!
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toLowerCase()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.testapp.TitleAdapter$1.performFiltering(TitleAdapter.java:92)
        at android.widget.Filter$RequestHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:234)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:171)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

I have been at this for hours and couldn't figure what am i doing wrong . Here is my adapter .

```
public class TitleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;
    private List <ItemObject> list;
    private List <ItemObject> listFiltered;
    private Context context;

    public TitleAdapter(Context context, List <ItemObject> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
        this.listFiltered = list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {
            View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.header_layout, parent, false);
            return new HeaderViewHolder(layoutView);
        } else if (viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
            View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
            return new ItemViewHolder(layoutView);
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("No match for " + viewType + ".");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ItemObject list = this.list.get(position);
        if (holder instanceof HeaderViewHolder) {
            ((HeaderViewHolder) holder).headerTitle.setText(list.getHeaderTitle());
        } else if (holder instanceof ItemViewHolder) {

            ((ItemViewHolder) holder).titleText.setText(list.getPageName());
        }
    }

    public ItemObject getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (isPositionHeader(position))
            return TYPE_HEADER;
        return TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    private boolean isPositionHeader(int position) {
        ItemObject mObject = list.get(position);
        return mObject.isHeader();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {

        return new Filter() {
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

                if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0){
                    listFiltered = list;
                } else {
                    String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();
                    List<ItemObject> lstFilter = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (ItemObject row : list) {

                        // name match condition. this might differ depending on your requirement
                        // here we are looking for name or phone number match
                        if (row.getPageName().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                            lstFilter.add(row);
                        }
                    }

                    listFiltered = lstFilter;
                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = listFiltered;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults results) {
                listFiltered = (List <ItemObject>) results.values;
                // refresh the list with filtered data
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };

    }

    public class HeaderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView headerTitle;

        public HeaderViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            headerTitle =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.headerText);

        }
    }

    public class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView titleText;

        public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            titleText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleText);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    int position = getAdapterPosition();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ViewerActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("PageName",list.get(position).getPageName());
                    intent.putExtra("PageUrl",list.get(position).getPageUrl());
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Btw if you are wondering this is line 92

```
 if (row.getPageName().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                            lstFilter.add(row);
                        }
```

Comment: 1.The constructor of the adapter is wong: `this.list = list; this.listFiltered = list;` which makes **list** and **listFiltered** the same instance. You should make them different instance. Try change it to: `this.list.addAll(list); this.listFiltered = list;`. 2.Looks like you want **list** as the full data, then your displayed data should be from **listFiltered**, so in **onBindViewHolder** change: `ItemObject list = this.list.get(position);` to `ItemObject list = this.listFiltered.get(position);` Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

As you know, there is `null` exception on `getPageName()` ,so just check it

```
if(row.getPageName()!=null && !row.getPageName().isEmpty())
 if (row.getPageName().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                            lstFilter.add(row);
                        }
```

and i see that you have `list` object in `getItemCount()`, so i assume the primary "List" is `list` so u have to back up this one and at this line do as follow :

```
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults results) {
                //listFiltered = (List <ItemObject>) results.values;
                //back up `list` some where else for reloading the list without filter
                list.clear();
                list.addAll((List <ItemObject>) results.values);

                // refresh the list with filtered data
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
```

back up the primary data and put the filter in

Comment: `  if(!row.getPageName()==null && !row.getPageName().isEmpty()) ` this line gives me error Operator '!' cannot be applied to 'java.lang.String'

Comment: my bad  try this way `if(row.getPageName()!=null...`

Comment: now when i click on the search icon my whole list disappears and nothing is shown

Comment: search something that is in the list . or maybe there is problem with your data list . log the for loop and print the `getPageName` to see if actually there is names.also put log on where enters the `if` statements  or not